# DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_CONTEXT_DESTROY failed

Tags: xorg

After I got stuck in login, I install Ubuntu 14.04 again. When I try to run my program, I got this error:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 293 requests (293 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_CONTEXT_DESTROY failed: No such file or directory
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_CONTEXT_DESTROY failed: No such file or directory
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_CONTEXT_DESTROY failed: No such file or directory
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_CONTEXT_DESTROY failed: No such file or directory
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_CONTEXT_DESTROY failed: No such file or directory
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_CONTEXT_DESTROY failed: No such file or directory
VW::ReadPPMImage(): unexpected end of file when reading header
VW::ReadPPMImage(): Bad magic number for PNM file
```

So, I can't convert my jpg file from my program, before I install the ubuntu, my program able to convert it.

This is my Xorg.0.log's warning:

```
[   715.962] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   715.962] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   715.963] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
```

This is my `lshw -C display`:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:43 memory:f6800000-f6bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: What program do you try to run? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I run MonoSLAMglow.
I try to sequence my jpg files. that jpg should convert automatically. and I failed to convert, because of the error.

Comment: How did you install MonoSLAMglow?

Comment: I followed this: [link] (http://www.hanmekim.com/openskill/howtoinstallscenelib10onubuntu1004) and (http://www.buiquanghuy.com/2012/06/install-monoslam-scenelib-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0):

MonoSLAMglow is *an example application* for the [SceneLib](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ajd/Scene/download.html) library.  So what this means is:

- If you're a programmer or a developer, this is an *extremely useful* application as it shows what the library can do.
- If you're an end-user, this application is of limited use: It contains errors and is not ready for day-to-day use.

If you want to convert images, there are tons of very useful applications under Ubuntu.  Just [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), describe what you want to accomplish and we will help you out...

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)